# iOS Firebase retrieve data from child nodes always nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read the Latitude and Longitude data, which is stored beneath a random child ID. My data structure is as follows:

[image]

This is my code for retrieving.

```
ref.child("locations").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
for child in snapshot.children  {
                let valueD = child as! DataSnapshot
                let randomkey = valueD.key
                print(randomkey)
                print(valueD.value)
                let lat = (valueD.value as? NSDictionary)?["Latitude"] as? String
                print(lat) 
}})
```

For `valueD.value`, the console prints this (which is correct)

```
Optional({
Latitude = "1.342433333333333";
Longitude = "103.9639883333333";
Type = 0;
})
```

However, for `lat`, it returns `nil`.

Why is there no value for `lat`? How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: First things first, try to print this (valueD.value as? NSDictionary). Check if you are getting dictionary output or not.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the response! It is indeed about a problem with unwrapping the Optional.

I tried the previous solutions. This solution worked best for me since I know from my database that I will definitely have Latitude and Longitude data: swap to exclamation marks.

```
let latitude = (valueD.value as! NSDictionary)["Latitude"] as! Double
```

Comment: Ah great! Looked like it was a String from your code but indeed could have been a Double as from your screenshot! Nice you found out!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `if let lat = child.value["Latitude"] as? Double` ? Like for example:

```
ref.child("locations").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
for child in snapshot.children  {

                let valueD = child as! DataSnapshot
                let randomkey = valueD.key
                print(randomkey)
                print(valueD.value)

                if let lat = child.value["Latitude"] as? Double {
                    print(lat)
                }
}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to safely unwrap the optional. There are many ways to do it. One of my favorite ways is to use a `guard let` statement

```
// This output already says 'Optional'
Optional({
Latitude = "1.342433333333333";
Longitude = "103.9639883333333";
Type = 0;
})
```

Unwrap it like this:

```
ref.child("locations").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
for child in snapshot.children  {

                let valueD = child as! DataSnapshot
                let randomkey = valueD.key
                print(randomkey)
                print(valueD.value)

                // Unwrap
                guard let childValue = valueD.value else { return }
                print(childValue["Latitude"])
}})
```